# Error moving lines/circles in CATIA drawing with VBA macro

Tags: vba, catia

I am writing a macro handling a title block in Catia drawings.
I have subs that I use to move circles and lines, which work fine (code initially found [here](https://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=345811))

```
Private Sub moveCircle(oCircle, dX As Double, dY As Double)
    Dim oCtr(1)
    oCircle.GetCenter oCtr
    
    movePoint oCircle.CenterPoint, dX, dY
    movePoint oCircle.StartPoint, dX, dY
    movePoint oCircle.EndPoint, dX, dY
    
    oCircle.SetData oCtr(0) + dX, oCtr(1) + dY, oCircle.Radius
    
    Debug.Print "move circle OK"
End Sub

Private Sub movePoint(oPt, dX As Double, dY As Double)
    Dim oCoord(1)

    oPt.GetCoordinates oCoord
    oPt.SetData oCoord(0) + dX, oCoord(1) + dY
End Sub

Private Sub moveLine(oLine, dX As Double, dY As Double)
    Dim oStartPt As Variant
    Dim oEndPt As Point2D
    Dim myDir(1)
    Dim oPtCoord(1)
    
    oLine.GetDirection myDir
    
    Set oStartPt = oLine.StartPoint
    Set oEndPt = oLine.EndPoint
    movePoint oStartPt, dX, dY
    movePoint oEndPt, dX, dY

    oStartPt.GetCoordinates oPtCoord
    
    oLine.SetData oPtCoord(0), oPtCoord(1), myDir(0), myDir(1)
End Sub
```

So those functions are called in a sub called "DrawView" when I create the drawing to move stuff around depending on the paper format, and everything works well.
If the paper format is changed later on, I want to resize everything and call those functions again from another sub "resizeTitleBlock", exactly the same way, and this is when it doesn't work anymore. I get an error saying the the method SetData in sub movePoint failed.

Those functions are called in both cases like this:

```
Dim element
        For Each element In refView.GeometricElements
            Select Case TypeName(element)
                Case "Axis2D":
                    'nothing to do, must be excldued
                Case "Line2D":
                    moveLine element, sheetWidth - 210, 0
                Case "Circle2D":
                    moveCircle element, sheetWidth - 210, 0
            End Select
        Next element
```

Any idea what may cause this issue?

I tried checking that the elements I pass to those functions are the same in both cases (by checking the name of the element). From Sub DrawView, "Line.1" is moved properly. From Sub resizeTitleBlock, I pass "Line.1" to the function again and get the error "the method SetData has failed".

I tried calling calling moveLine from Sub DrawView several times, and it works.

Comment: Does this line have any constraints? Can you move this line by hand (drag)? Does this problem occur only on this specific line?

Comment: No, no constraints, I can move them by hand. It happens on every Line or Circle.

Comment: Does your macro work if the background view (where your geometries are located) is active?

Comment: No it doesn't! I tried with the background view active or inactive, and it had to be active indeed. So I found the solution which is to add a refView.Activate before calling the functions. Thank you!